# Google API direction returns 0 result

Tags: android

My problem when I send google api direction request for the first time I got the result so draw a **polyline** on my map but after I don't what happened the give 0 result

[image: this what i got from request]

**https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-90.0,37.574625&destination=-5.54372068494558,33.8867111850552&mode=driving&key=map_api_key**

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the latitude and longitude values in the URL it looks like you're trying to find a route between the north pole and somewhere in Tanzania. Google maps correctly returns 0 routes because there are no routes between these 2 points.

-90.0 latitude is always the north pole.

The URL itself is formatted correctly and if you enter 2 latitude and longitude values for origin and destination that are possible to reach each other you will get a `route` object back.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-4.3843065,34.3452336&destination=-5.54372068494558,33.8867111850552&mode=driving&key=map_api_key